# How to selectively marshal JSON for a struct?

Tags: go

I have a struct:

```
type Paper struct {
    PID    int    `json:"pID"`
    PTitle string `json:"pTitle"`
    PDesc  string `json:"pDesc"`
    PPwd   string `json:"pPwd"`
}
```

Mostly, I will encode the entire struct to JSON. However, occasionally, I need 
the brief version of the struct; i.e. encode some of the properties, how should I implement this feature?

```
type BriefPaper struct {
    PID    int    `json:"-"`      // not needed
    PTitle string `json:"pTitle"`
    PDesc  string `json:"pDesc"`
    PPwd   string `json:"-"`      // not needed
}
```

I am thinking of creating a subset struct, something like `BriefPaper = SUBSET(Paper)`, but not sure how to implement it in Golang.

I hope I can do something like this:

```
p := Paper{ /* ... */ }
pBrief := BriefPaper{}

pBrief = p;
p.MarshalJSON(); // if need full JSON, then marshal Paper
pBrief.MarshalJSON(); // else, only encode some of the required properties
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to create a struct embeds `Paper`, and shadows the fields you want to hide:

```
type Paper struct {
    PID    int    `json:"pID"`
    PTitle string `json:"pTitle"`
    PDesc  string `json:"pDesc"`
    PPwd   string `json:"pPwd"`
}

type BriefPaper struct {
    Paper
    PID    int    `json:"pID,omitempty"`  // Just make sure you 
    PPwd   string `json:"pPwd,omitempty"` // don't set these fields!
}

p := Paper{ /* ... */ }
pBrief := BriefPaper{Paper: p}
```

Now when marshaing `BriefPaper`, the fields `PID` and `PPwd` will be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Why you just do like this below

```
type SubPaper struct {
    PID    int    `json:"pID"`
    PPwd   string `json:"pPwd"`
}
```

```
type Paper struct {
    SubPaper
    PTitle string `json:"pTitle"`
    PDesc  string `json:"pDesc"`
}
```

And then marshal the Paper if you want full response

and SubPaper selective things

Comment: But how can I interchange the struct, such as `subPaper = paper`? Can I directly assign it?

Comment: I don't understand what you say about interchange but you can use interface like this  `var sub interface{}`  and then assign like this  `sub = SubPaper{}` or `sub = Paper{}` interface will overcome your problem. But I don't know what's your exact problem ?

Comment: No, you can't directly assign it in this case. This approach will definitely work, but it's cumbersome to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Using omitempty in tag. Need not specify the items to include while creating the struct instance.

```
type Paper struct {
    PID    int    `json:"pID,omitempty"`
    PTitle string `json:"pTitle"`
    PDesc  string `json:"pDesc"`
    PPwd   string `json:"pPwd,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    u := Paper{PTitle: "Title 1", PDesc: "Desc 1"}
    b, _ := json.Marshal(u)

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Prints: {"pTitle":"Title 1","pDesc":"Desc 1"}

Only problem is if PID is 0 explicitly then still it will omit it.

Like:

> Paper{PTitle: "Title 1", PDesc: "Desc 1", PID:0}
>   Then it will still print {"pTitle":"Title 1","pDesc":"Desc 1"}

**Another way to do it using embedded type:**

Note that the embedded type has to be pointer so that it can be nil and omitempty can then exclude it.

```
type Paper struct {
    PID    int    `json:"pID"`    
    PPwd   string `json:"pPwd"`
}

type BriefPaper struct {    
    PTitle string `json:"pTitle"`
    PDesc  string `json:"pDesc"`
    *Paper `json:",omitempty"`  
}

func main() {
    u := BriefPaper{PTitle: "Title 1", PDesc: "Desc 1"}
    b, _ := json.Marshal(u)

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Prints: {"pTitle":"Title 1","pDesc":"Desc 1"}

If nested inner struct for paper is required, tag it like *Paper `json:"paper,omitempty"`

Comment: Corrected, missed to see that. A embedded pointer type is required. If you want nested inner struct, tag it like *Paper `json:"paper,omitempty"`

Comment: This approach actually doesn't work at all. See [here](https://play.golang.org/p/o486DimYhNz). I'm pretty sure json tags on an embedded value have no effect at all.

Comment: Omitempty means omit if empty. So inner has to be nil in this case. The way I have used.  https://play.golang.org/p/FGLmHshW9EH

Comment: I know what omit empty means. That doesn't have any bearing on whether json tags mean anything on an embedded struct. See also: https://play.golang.org/p/ynZuspUZHkn

Comment: It does look like it _can_ have an effect: https://play.golang.org/p/wD4XzBqOv6i  But that still doesn't help the OP's situation.

Comment: Was about to post what you just posted. If it doesn't help OP, my bad; leave it. I will delete the post if you insist, I thought omitempty could be one of the viable option.

Comment: I don't insist. :) It's your post. Do with it as you will. I just don't think that approach helps.